# Is it legal to have independent shared_ptrs pointing to same object?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Many articles about `shared_ptr` warn against accidentally creating independent `shared_ptr`s to same object.
For instance, [this article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this). It has comment `// Bad, each shared_ptr thinks it's the only owner of the object`.

But what if that's exactly the kind of behaviour I want? For example:

```cpp
auto* object = new Object();
auto ptr1 = std::shared_ptr<Object>(object);
auto ptr2 = std::shared_ptr<Object>(object, [ptr1](Object* obj){ obj->cleanup(); });
ptr2 = nullptr;
ptr1 = nullptr;
```

This works perfectly on GCC 6.3, but is it *legal* to do so, i.e. does standard permit such usage?

Comment: This is fine, but then why would you ever want to do this?

Comment: @Jarod42 Note that the deleter of `ptr2` also contributes to the ownership of the deleter of `ptr1`. If you get rid of `ptr1` first, the deleter of `ptr2` still keeps the control block active, and will call the `delete` after `ptr2`'s control block is freed

Comment: @KABoissonneault: Oh, don't see the capture...

Comment: Why not simply: `auto ptr1 = std::shared_ptr<Object>(new Object, [](Object* obj){ obj->cleanup(); delete obj; }); auto ptr2 = ptr1;` ?

Comment: @PasserBy Basically I'm writing a library where objects live in specific threads. I don't want user to concurrently delete those objects from outside threads, so I'd like to use custom deleter that will merely schedule deleting. However I also want to use actual shared_ptr with default deleter in implementation for internal lifetime management.

Comment: And why would you want specifically a default deleter?

Comment: @PasserBy to delete objects of course. Actually library is a wrapper around boost::asio, and I'd like to capture `shared_from_this()` in all asynchronous operations to prolong its life until every operation completes (rather popular approach). So, like I said, for internal lifetime management.

Comment: "a wrapper around boost::asio' - uh oh. You've probably missed the point of asio.

Comment: The question is ambiguous, as you don't indicate if you expect from_this support or what you would expect as from_this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having two shared_ptr objects owning the same object will work some of the time. Where it will not work is where the `Object` is derived from `std::enable_shared_from_this<Object>`. In this case the magic during the assignment to the shared_ptr will cause you undefined behaviour.

> The constructors of std::shared_ptr detect the presence of an unambiguous and accessible (since C++17) enable_shared_from_this base and assign the newly created std::shared_ptr to the internally stored weak reference if not already owned by a live std::shared_ptr (since C++17). Constructing a std::shared_ptr for an object that is already managed by another std::shared_ptr will not consult the internally stored weak reference and thus will lead to undefined behavior.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this

> I don't want user to concurrently delete those objects from outside threads, so I'd like to use custom deleter that will merely schedule deleting.

The solution will depend on whether the cleanup operation will need the shared count (i.e. does it take longer than one tick).

simple case:

```
auto deleter = [&scheduler](Object* p)
{
    auto delete_impl = [p]()
    {
        p->cleanup();
        delete p;
    };
    scheduler.post(delete_impl);
};

auto po = std::shared_ptr<Object>(new Object(), deleter);
```

less simple case:

In the case where the cleanup might take longer than one 'tick', it is not clear to me from the documentation at cppreference whether it is valid to reassign `p` to another `shared_ptr<Object>` for the cleanup phase. Even if it strictly is, its such a dark corner that I would not trust the behaviour to be standardised across all library implementations.

For safety, let's define a new object to act as a shared handle during the cleanup:

```
struct DyingObjectHandle : std::enable_shared_from_this<DyingObjectHandle>
{
  DyingObjectHandle(Object* p) : p(p) {}

  void cleanup()
  {
    auto self = shared_from_this();
    ... etc
  }

  void final_destroy()
  {
    delete p;
  }

  Object *p;
};
```

And then modify the deleter:

```
auto deleter = [&scheduler](Object* p)
{
    auto doh = std::make_shared<DyingObjectHandle>(p);
    scheduler.post([doh = std::move(doh)]()
    {
        doh->cleanup();
    });
};

auto po = std::shared_ptr<Object>(new Object(), deleter);
```

Finally:

> Actually library is a wrapper around boost::asio

This is often a source common inefficiencies.

An `asio::io_context` should normally be thought of as a singleton object for an entire application. It represents "the application-wide IO scheduling loop". Maximum concurrency is achieved when N threads are running the same `io_context`, each io-enabled object has its own `strand` and all handlers are scheduled through the strands, eg:

```
timer_.async_wait(asio::bind_executor(my_strand_, 
                  [self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec)
{
   // ...handle the timer.
});
```

In this way, it is irrelevant which thread handler completes on. If multiple concurrent operations occur on the same io object, they will be serialised through the strand *more efficiently* than if they were all contending on the same mutex or tied to a specific thread's `io_context`.

Answer (score 0):

It is legal. The only thing not legal would be to double-delete the pointed object. You prevent this by having one `shared_ptr` use a custom deleter.

Is it good practice? Would it pass code review? Would it raise eyebrows? You decide for yourself.

I would try hard not to use constructs like this.

Answer (score 0):

What you show appears to be legal.

> I don't want user to concurrently delete those objects from outside threads, so I'd like to use custom deleter that will merely schedule deleting.

I suggest alternative approach: Simply use one level of shared pointers with a custom deleter. In the deleter, add the pointer into a thread safe queue to be destroyed in the correct thread. A simple approach would be to store unique pointers in the queue and then simply clear the queue to release the memory.